# PROLOG - What is an accurate answer for a proof?

Tags: prolog, computer-science

So I have a family tree proof that has over 10 subgoals regarding relationships.

My program satisfies all the subgoals required for the proof.

proof(ME) :- dad(X,ME), brother(Y,ME) . . . so on.

When I execute the proof(ME). I get X = me for each subgoal as an output.

```
X = me;
X = me;
X = me;
.... so on
```

Is that right or it has to output true or yes ? If so, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please ensure that your question includes everything someone else would need to see the problem themselves (the [mre] rules call for a question to include the *shortest possible* version of your code that still generates the problem at hand). We can't say what correct output should be for code we haven't seen in enough detail to walk through its execution by hand (or run ourselves, as appropriate).

Comment: If your query succeeds, Prolog demonstrates that by outputting the bindings that were established. Implementations sometimes output `yes` if your query has no variables or if they remain unbound. The bindings that are not surfaced to the outermost query are not output (and in practice you wouldn't want them to anyway, since there might be a huge amount of behind-the-scenes state being calculated).